# How come my php settings on CLI and Apache are different? (OSX Lion Server)

Tags: macos, apache, php, osx-lion

I am currently setting up my New Mac Mini Lion server. 
I am now installing mongodb and apc extension.
I want to include the ini settings for the extensions on the /etc/php.d directory (similar with my server settings on centOS)

I tried to do

```
php -i | grep php.d
```

and it gives me

```
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php.d/
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php.d/apc.ini,
/etc/php.d/mongo.ini
PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR => /etc/php.d/
_SERVER["PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR"] => /etc/php.d/
```

But when I tried on phpinfo() on a php script, I got:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc
Loaded Configuration File   /private/etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     (none)
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
```

The php environment on CLI and php script is the same
which php

> /usr/bin/php

and on php script page

> PATH  /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Is there anything I should set on the apache side?

I am thinking to stick with the Built-in apache and php from the mac installation because I like the Server App from Mac.

Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: You might try asking at http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did this the other night, although it was not on Lion Server.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

uncomment (delete the `#`)

```
#LoadModule php5_module   libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

save with `ctrl`+`o` then `Enter`

then restart apache

```
sudo apachectl restart -t
```

Additionally, you will need to

```
cd /etc
sudo cp php.ini.default php.ini
sudo chmod 666 php.ini
```

I would also recommend configuring php.ini (basically every module is disabled).

Comment: I have done all this, but still unable to load ini files on etc/php.d from the phpinfo(), but it is loaded in the CLI php -i